# Plot contours for 3d histograms

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, histograms

I have a `data` set which is a list of pairs. From this I can easily make a 3d histogram with `Histogram3D[data]` or a smoothed projection of it to the plane with `SmoothDensityHistogram[data]`. What I would like to obtain is a smoothed contour line within which the data count has a given value or higher. Essentially this would be a single customizable contour line in the plot produced by `SmoothDensityHistogram[data]`. 
Ultimately I would need to combine several such contour lines in a single plot. How would I achieve this?

I investigated a bit and found that this approach

```
data1 = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.75], 10];
distribution1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data1];
data2 = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.75], 10];
distribution2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data2];

Sow[ContourPlot[
  PDF[distribution1, {x, y}] == 10^(-2), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.4], ContourShading -> None], 
ContourPlot[
  PDF[distribution2, {x, y}] == 10^(-2), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.4], ContourShading -> None]]
```

should be producing what I want.

The remaining problem is that the resulting plot shows only one of the contour lines as if the background of the plots was not transparent. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know but is it really possible to define a single contour that would encompass say 60% of the data points? I'd say there will be a multitude of contours that do that.

Comment: Sorry, wrong phrasing! It should plot a maximum likelihood contour rather than that, i.e. one within which the probability has a given value or more. Of course there can be a set of disconnected such contours and, of course, it won't be unique either because it will depend on the smoothing.

Comment: Doesn't look like a usable definition either.

Comment: Let's put it this way: The histogram gets me an integer value (count) for each of a finite number of 2-dimensional bins. I then apply a (to be defined) smoothing algorithm which gives a smooth function `f(x,y)` of two variables (I could turn it into a probability distribution function by normalization). I want to plot a specific contour line which satisfies `f(x,y)=const`. As I mentioned this this would be a contour line in a `SmoothDensityHistogram[]` plot.

Comment: But that contour describes a local density and it does neither relate to the total data count within the contour (original question)  nor the probability of finding a member of the data set within the contour (update in comment) which is what you seem to want. If you simply want the density contours from a SmoothDensityHistogram why don't you use that?

Comment: As I said this has been a wrong phrasing. I want a contour line of a probability distribution corresponding to a smoothed histogram. I could as well ask how do I isolate a single contour from `SmoothDensityHistogram` (I don't want the smooth function itself) and combine it with other such contours corresponding to different histograms.

Comment: You can get two contour lines just like this: `ContourPlot[{  PDF[distribution1, {x, y}] == 10^(-2),  PDF[distribution2, {x, y}] == 10^(-2)} ...`

Comment: Works. Why don't you edit your answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit, based on the added info in the question:

```
 data1 = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.75], 10];
 distribution1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data1];
 data2 = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.75], 10];
 distribution2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data2];
 ContourPlot[
     {PDF[distribution1, {x, y}] == 10^(-2),
      PDF[distribution2, {x, y}] == 10^(-2)}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
       ContourStyle -> {Red,Blue}, ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

something like this?

```
 r = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 100];
 hg = Histogram3D[r]
```

[image]

```
 hl = HistogramList[r];
 Show[hg, Graphics3D[{Thick, Red, 
    Map[Append[#, 5] & , First@Cases[Normal@First@
    Cases[ListContourPlot[ 
      Flatten[Table[{
         Mean@hl[[1, 1, j ;; j + 1]], 
         Mean@hl[[1, 2, i ;; i + 1]],
         hl[[2, j, i]]},
         {i, Length@hl[[1, 2]] - 1}, {j, Length@hl[[1, 1]] - 1}], 1], 
            Contours -> {5}], _GraphicsComplex, Infinity],
           _Line, Infinity], {2}]}]]
```

[image]

By the way, It would be cleaner to work with `SmoothDensityHistogram`, but I can't figure how to coax it to give a single contour line at a specified level..

Comment: This is the correct direction, however I do need only two contour lines and I need it smoothed (see my recent edit to the question).

Answer (score 7):

**Update:**

```
SeedRandom[123]
d1 = BinormalDistribution[.75];
r = RandomVariate[d1, 20];
hg = Histogram3D[r, Automatic, "PDF", ChartStyle -> Opacity[.35]];
sh = SmoothHistogram3D[r, Automatic, "PDF", BoundaryStyle -> None,  PlotStyle -> None,
   Mesh -> {{{.03, Directive[Thick, Orange]}, {.11, Directive[Thick, Red]}}}];
Row[{Show[hg, sh, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 400],
  Show[hg, sh /. Line[x_] :> {Line[x], EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Opacity[.4]], Polygon[x]},
   PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

[image]

Using `SmoothKernelDistribution` of data with `Plot3D` and `MeshFunctions`:

```
d2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[r];
plt3d = Plot3D[Evaluate[PDF[#, {x, y}]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
     MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{.03}},
     MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Purple], Directive[Thick, Brown]}[[#2]], 
     PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
     ClippingStyle -> None] & @@@ {{d1, 1}, {d2, 2}};
Legended[Show[hg, plt3d,
  PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> 1], LineLegend[{Purple, Brown},
  (Style[#, 16, "Panel"]&/@{"PDF[Binormal[.7]]", "PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[r]]"})]]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Show[hg, Plot3D[Evaluate[PDF[#, {x, y}]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
     MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{mesh}},
     MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Purple], Directive[Thick, Brown]}[[#2]], 
     PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None,
     ClippingStyle -> None] & @@@ {{d1, 1}, {d2, 2}},
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {0, .25}}, BoxRatios -> 1],
 {{mesh, .03}, .01, .20}]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

Maybe something like:

```
r = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 100];
hg = Histogram3D[r, Automatic, "PDF", ChartStyle -> Opacity[.5]];

sh = SmoothHistogram3D[r, Automatic, "PDF", 
   Mesh -> {{{.05, Directive[Thick, Orange]}, {.12, Directive[Thick, Red]}}},
   BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> None];

Show[hg, sh]
```

[image]

```
Show[hg, sh /. Line[x_] :> {Opacity[.8], Polygon[x]}]
```

[image]